# Entity Framework DbContext Delete child object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I am trying to delete the child objects in foreach loop but that doesn't seem to be working.. Here is what I have.
I have a meeting and meeting_category entities which has 1-to-many relationship..

```
    foreach (meeting_category meetingCategory in currentMeeting.meeting_category)
            {
              dbContext.meeting_category.Remove(meetingCategory);
              dbContext.Entry(meetingCategory).State = EntityState.Deleted;
              dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
```

I am then returning to the same view with updated results.. This seems to be very inconsistent. Sometimes it deletes entities and sometimes it doesn't. Even when it deletes it, my meeting object still have meeting_category objects I deleted.

When it doesn't delete from DB, it updates the meeting object and removed meeting_category objects from the meeting..
Is there any kind of reset or refresh that I will have to do in order for meeting object to remove the meeting_category objects..
How can I make sure that it consistently deletes the meeting_category objects both from DB and from the meeting object and when I return to the view, I have an updated meeting object?

Here is my meeting entity

```
    public partial class meeting
    {
        public meeting()
        {
            this.meeting_questions = new HashSet<meeting_questions>();
            this.meeting_abstract = new HashSet<meeting_abstract>();
            this.meeting_category = new HashSet<meeting_category>();
            this.meeting_image = new HashSet<meeting_image>();
        }

        public int meeting_id { get; set; }
        public int language_id { get; set; }
        public string meeting_code { get; set; }
        public string meeting_name { get; set; }
        public string meeting_description { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime meeting_start_date { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime meeting_end_date { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime abstract_cutoff_date { get; set; }
        public string meeting_guidelines { get; set; }
        public string created_by { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> created_datetime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> meeting_published { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> meeting_deleted { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> meeting_fully_created { get; set; }

        public virtual language language { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<meeting_questions> meeting_questions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<meeting_abstract> meeting_abstract { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<meeting_category> meeting_category { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<meeting_image> meeting_image { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is my meeting_category entity

```
 public partial class meeting_category
    {
        public meeting_category()
        {
            this.abstract_category = new HashSet<abstract_category>();
        }

        public int meeting_category_id { get; set; }
        public int meeting_id { get; set; }
        public int category_type_id { get; set; }
        public int category_id { get; set; }
        public string category_name { get; set; }
        public string category_name_en { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<abstract_category> abstract_category { get; set; }
        public virtual category category { get; set; }
        public virtual category_type category_type { get; set; }
        public virtual meeting meeting { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Whre do you create the context? Where do your entities come from? It's fundamental to know what you're doing with teh context, and if your entities are atatched to it or detached. It's also necessary to know how you read your entities. The context can cache entities, and that can lead to problems if you don't use correctly. Please, add some more info to ypur question

Comment: Hi JotaBe, My DBContext is created using the Entity Model generator in visual studio. We are using the SQL server entities in DbContext. Our entities are attached entities. I think context caching of entities seems to be an issue. Can you please guide me on it? Please let me know if you need any other information

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of questions about what it is that you are trying to achieve.

Firstly are you sure that the Meeting -> Category relationship is many-to-one? I would normally expect it to be many-to-many, i.e. each Meeting can have many Categories and each Category can be attached to many Meetings.

Secondly, are you actually trying to delete the Category or are you trying to remove a Category from a Meeting?

If you are simply trying to remove the relationship between a Meeting and a Category then you need to edit the navigation property, i.e. MyMeeting.Categories.Remove(MyCategory).

If you are trying to delete the actual Category then you will need to make sure that that Category is not currently linked to any Meeting otherwise you will get a Foreign Key violation if you try to remove the Category.

On top of all of this you may be encountering chaching or simply object lifetime management issues.

What type of application are you creating? ASP.NET? WinForms? etc.

How are you actually instantiating a concrete version of your DBContext? Are you using DI?

Cheers Mike

Comment: Mike, Meeting -> Category has one-to-many relationship. One meeting can have many meeting_category objects. I am actually trying to delete the meeting categories. Actually what I am trying to accomplish is that I have a meeting_category selection page where they can select the multiple categories for one particular meeting. Adding the meeting_category is working fine for the meeting. When they want to Edit those categories, they can again check/uncheck the required ones and submit the page. When they post it, I am trying to delete the old ones and that is where it is causing an issue.

Comment: @AndyJohnson That would make the relationship a many-to-many relationship as I am pretty sure that it will be possible to have different meetings that have the same category. Correct?

Comment: No..I have a separate category table that displays the category selection. For each meeting, I have separate rows for each category. So  for the other meeting, I can have same category selected but will be in different row with meeting_id and meeting_category_id different. Please let me know if you need further clarification on it. I am in desperate need for a help.

Comment: Everything that you say still leads me to believe that this is a many-to-many relationship. Can you please post the actual entity definitions for those two entities to make sure. Also you should find that in the DB that EF creates there is a linking table. It shouldn't actually matter as you will get the Foreign Key violation errors if you try to delete a category if it is already in use in either scenario. Can you please answer all the other questions and then test the Foreign Key issue? i.e. does it work fine if the category is not in use?

Comment: Also what is the following line of code doing?

 dbContext.Entry(meetingCategory).State = EntityState.Deleted;

I am pretty sure it is not needed.

Comment: Mike, here is my meeting entity

Comment: Sorry @AndyJohnson nothing is showing. Could you make sure that you post both the Meeting and the Meeting_Category entity. Thanks.

Comment: Mike, I have added the meeting and meeting_category entities to my original model since I was not able to add that here in the comment

Comment: Also, I know that dbContext.Entry(meetingCategory).State = EntityState.Deleted;  is probably not needed. This is actually what I tried to check and see if it is working by marking the entity dirty.. I also tried getting the meeting object back from the database using the dbContext but that also doesn't help.

Comment: I have another question (and I still need you to answer all the other questions that I have posed). Are you using a model-first or a code-first architecture?

Comment: Mike, I am using model-first architecture. It is an asp.net MVC application using MVC5 and EF 5. I don't exactly understand how do i instentiate the dbContext.. but here is what I use. var dbContext = new MeetingEntities();

Comment: Mike, Now I get the error "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

Comment: Can you please let me know what MeetingEntities is. Also I am still not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to delete a category, or are you simply trying to remove a category from a specific meeting?

Comment: Also the error you are getting is because you are changing the Collection that you are currently enumerating over (i.e. you are modifying the list that the For Each is looking at). If you want to empty the entire collection then simply use MyMeeting.Categories.Clear();

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue by creating the DbContext per controller action and destroying it before loading the view. 
The problem was that I was creating the DbContext in another class and was reusing the same context on all controller action. Since Entities are cached in dbcontext, I was always getting the old cached copy of entities and was working very inconsistently.